# MySQL fetch a field where the field exists > x times in table

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1111

I'm trying to do the following in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field
FROM table
WHERE COUNT(field) > 10
```

Which fails with: 1111 - Invalid use of group function (from what I understand, you can't use group functions such as `COUNT` in the where clause?)

What is the proper way of selecting (distinct) all fields which are present in at least **N** rows? Is this something I'll have to do externally with say, PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field
  FROM table
HAVING COUNT(field) > 10
```

You can't use aggregate functions outside of a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  Which is why you need to use the `HAVING` clause.  Also [keep in mind that `COUNT` counts ***non-null values***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)...

Ideally, there should be a `GROUP BY` clause as well.  But [MySQL is rather lax about that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

### To compare *all* the columns

...you're going to have to add a `GROUP BY` clause that lists *all those columns*--there's no shorthand in this case. Then change the `HAVING` clause to `COUNT(*) > 10`.

Comment: Possibly I'm misunderstanding, but when I run that I always get 1 row returned, even when several rows in the database exist much more than 10 times. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahdi.Montgomery: To compare *all* the columns, you're going to have to add a `GROUP BY` clause that lists all those columns--there's no shorthand in this case.  Then change the `HAVING` clause to `COUNT(*) > 10`.  It's a lot easier to help you if you provide the CREATE TABLE statement.